# How can I switch the database provider used by EF Core based on configuration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

EF Core supports a lot of [different providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) and I can configure them in `Startup.cs` by specifying the provider. For example, if I want to use SQL Server, I can use:

```
services.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(options => {
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SomeDatabase"));
});
```

But the DB provider (SQL Server) seems to be hard-coded here. What I want to achieve is set the DB provider based on configuration so I can switch the DB provider based on configuration.

Is there a way to switch provider based on config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but it's a bit manual. You have access to the config from here, so you can just do something like:

```
services.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(options => Configuration["DatabaseProvider"] switch
{
  "someprovider" => options.UseSomeOtherProvider(...),
  // etc.
  _ => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SomeDatabase"))
});
```

I'm using the newer switch expression syntax here. The last line with `_` implies the default when there's no explicit match.

Comment: I was hoping for something that is entirely config based. I remeber being able to set the provider in config in EF6, but this could work as well.

Comment: This is the best you can do with EF Core. The difference is the use of DI. Different services need to be registered, so it happens in code.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. YOu must make your own factory method. See, this is not just configuring - this is also loading the classes. There is no registration mechanism for this anymore in web.config.